# Redirect to a website with cloudflare 5 second protection C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to do a http get request to a page with a json result so i can parse it and do my things.

The website always have the cloudflare 5 second protection, or waits 5 seconds before it redirects in my chrome browser, but in my c# application i always get a 503 error with a http get or http post. I tried many ways with allowredirect=true but i just can't do it! Can someone help me?

I need to wait 5 seconds and then get the correct page. Any way to do it?

Comment: It is not waiting 5 seconds - I think it does something in those 5 seconds you fail to do. This protection is made to keep bots out (advanced DDOS) and your access looks perfectly like a bot (which does not run javascript).

Comment: Any way to get the information from the website? webbrowser works in c# but how can i get my json information?

Comment: Ask Cloudflare not to protect your JSON content.  The 5 second redirect requires Javascript to run or you get a 503.

Comment: Yeah. Basically read the documentation / contact their support and find out how to bypass the DDOS protection for certain URL's.

Comment: Do you solve your problem, I have the same problem